# Can't import MobileDevice module in Swift

Tags: swift

Its location (on 10.11) is:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework
```

and when I try to import it after adding it to a MacOSX Swift project with this statement:

```
import MobileDevice
```

in a Swift file, I am getting an:

> No such module

What's happening?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the Xcode Project by using shortcut (Command+Shift+K)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cleaning your Xcode Project doesn't work, try going to your Build Settings in Xcode and define the Framework Search Path to the path of the MobileDevice Framework. So in your case you would set the Framework Search Path to:

> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework

Also, if the framework is located in the project directory use $(SRCROOT) and set it to recursive.